# Facebook API permissions issue for Instant Articles

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-instant-articles

I am trying to make a POST request to the Facebook API to create instant articles, like so:

```
curl \
-F 'access_token={access token}' \
-F 'html_source="<!doctype html><html>blah blah blah</html>"' \
-F 'published=true' \
-F 'development_mode=false' \
https://graph.facebook.com/{page-id}/instant_articles
```

I am an admin for the app, and when I debug my access token, the scope shows `email, pages_show_list, pages_manage_instant_articles, public_profile`, but the request returns this error:

```
{"error":
    {"message":"(#200) Requires pages_manage_instant_articles permission to manage the object",
    "type":"OAuthException",
    "code":200,
    "fbtrace_id":"Exyv2VtZ5m4"}
}
```

Anyone have any ideas about what's going on? Thanks and let me know if you need more info!

Comment: How were you able to get a token with the `pages_manage_instant_articles` permission? I tried doing the same but it requires me to submit my Facebook app for review, when I really only want it for my own page.

Answer (score 2):

Solved! I added the version to the url. 
`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/{page-id}/instant_articles`

Answer (score 0):

When I first worked with Graph API I faced the same issue but that was in Android.

Although the solution in my case, user / admin have to sign in first and give permission to access facebook data using GraphAPI

Comment: is that specific permission I'm missing, or do i just need to log in? logging in first doesn't seem to be making a difference, unless I'm doing it incorrectly.